# How accurately can an asteroid's path be calculated?

Tags: astrophysics, astronomy

I have read a bit about the asteroid 99942 Apophis, and I have found that its approach in 2029 is predicted to be as close as 31,200km.

I may be oversimplifying this a little, but given the Earth orbits the Sun at 30km per second, then surely the "ETA" of the asteroid on Earth's orbit only has to be wrong by just over a thousand seconds for it to hit Earth.

I appreciate that even if the predictions are wrong, the likelihood of an impact on Earth is still relatively small, but surely it isn't possible to predict the position of an asteroid in 11 years time to within just over a quarter of an hour? Therefore, how come the possibility of an impact with Earth has been completely eliminated?

Comment: It could be that the 31,200 km distance refers to how far apart the planes of orbit of Earth and Apophis will be, instead of how far ahead or behind they will be from where the paths cross.

Comment: @TomB. I hadn't thought of that actually. Reading Wikipedia though, it does say that the asteroid will pass within the orbits of geosynchronous satellites, so one would assume that this means it is on the same plane as these satellites and therefore the same would be true for Earth's orbit.

Comment: Huh, interesting. But that brings up the possibility of an in-plane but "sideways" miss, and I just looked up geosynchronous orbit and it's 35,786 km! Coincidence? I hope someone answers definitively.

Comment: @TomB. Having done some more research, it appears that the plane is inclined at 40 degrees to the Earth's equator.

Comment: @PhysicsGuy123 - The orbital ephemeris data are updated every ~10 years or so and when this is done it is done down to 6-15 decimal places, depending on the parameter (e.g., see http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2002P%26SS...50..217F).  That being said, they often update near Earth object trajectories whenever new data is presented and the projections almost always change, at least a little.

Comment: @honeste_vivere - when you say the new data usually means the projections change by a little, roughly how much could they change by? As I understand it, Apophis' projection was last updated in 2013, and obviously it will have its close pass in 2029. If this were to be a "sideways miss", then surely 15-20 minutes would be a percentage uncertainty of about 0.0002%. I struggle to understand how they can be so confident that it won't impact when the margins are so small.

Comment: @PhysicsGuy123 - The magnitude of the changes depend upon lots of things, but most importantly (my guess) is the quality of the original observations.  That is, the accuracy and duration of observation of the orbital data for Apophis will likely determine how well they can project to later dates.  The changes due to updated epoch/ephemeris data would depend upon the $\Delta t$ from the prior epoch/ephemeris (i.e., larger $\Delta t$ would typically result in larger changes for updated values).